# Why do we use "used to" to form a past tense?

Tags: tense, past-tense

To propose a deed happening in the past, we can exercise the past form of the verb for that action or state. I know one of the usages of "used to" is for the construction of a past sentence.

How common is it for a native to use it?
Is it natural that we use it for other tenses like “**It used to have been working before you came in**”?

Comment: "used to"is used for a past habit that has stopped. For example: I used to smoke, but I quit smoking 4 years ago. In the past I had the habit of smoking, but this is no longer true. Your example makes no sense, you can say: "I was working before you came in".

Comment: It is commonly used, but only when referring to something that was habitual in the past. _I used to live in London. When I was a child we used to go for a seaside holiday every year._

Comment: @KateBunting can we say " When I used to be a child we used to go for a seaside holiday every year"?

Comment: _When I used to be a child_ is a very odd thing to say. Since everybody was a child once, _I used to be a child_ is a possible thing to say,  but unusual, and means that you are emphasising the fact that you are not a child any more. That emphasis is inconsistent with using the clause as a temporal focus with "when".